# Newbie on linux. Does my webcam have a microphone?

Tags: sound, webcam, microphone, logitech, cheese

I was able to get a **Logitech web cam** to work with Cheese, after reading some helpful tips on the site. But how do we know if the "microphone" is attached or working? OR if there is even one on the camera.

Sorry, no idea on tech details of the webcam, no label or part number on it; got it from a bin with no box or manual.

**OR** do I need to get a headset with a microphone?

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:0804 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C250
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x046d **Logitech, Inc.**
  idProduct          0x0804 **Webcam C250**
  bcdDevice            0.09
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 2 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength         1549
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength          217
        dwClockFrequency       48.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x0000000e
          Auto-Exposure Mode

          Auto-Exposure Priority
          Exposure Time (Absolute)
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier      16384
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000175b
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          White Balance Temperature
          Backlight Compensation
          Gain
          Power Line Frequency
          White Balance Temperature, Auto
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x1b
          None
          NTSC - 525/60
          SECAM - 625/50
          NTSC - 625/50
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                27
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {82066163-7050-ab49-b8cc-b3855e8d221e}
        bNumControl            10
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls( 0)       0xff
        bmControls( 1)       0x03
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                27
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                13
        guidExtensionCode         {82066163-7050-ab49-b8cc-b3855e8d221f}
        bNumControl             7
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          2
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls( 0)       0x6f
        bmControls( 1)       0x01
        iExtension              0 
.....  


 AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 **Microphone**
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             1
        wChannelConfig     0x0000
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          1
        bSourceID               5
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
```

OK, So its a C250 model and I guess there is a microphone based on the output above...

Comment: Thanks but there is NOTHING printed on or under the webcam itself. JUST the logo and the words "logitech" on it, above the lens. There are 2 slots under the lens. But I have no idea how to "test" for sound on this PC. I am less than 4 days on my journey into Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, that was the easy way. Please open a terminal window, and run this command: _lsusb -v_ then highlight the resulting text, copy that text with Ctrl-Shift-C, then return here, click [edit], and paste it into your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: In *Settings>Sound>Input* is an internal microphone listed as a selectable input? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.